# Exception handling in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I have a procedure that gets data from a table and inserts it into a temporary table. Then
the procedure validates one by one in a while loop.

For example: I have 50 rows and the first row fails. In that case, I wish that the procedure continues processing the remaining 49 rows.

I'm forcing an error in an insert statement and and I put under it `@@error <> 0` but does not enter if block.

But procedure ends and doesn't continues with the next statement to be executed.

I am running the procedure from Query Analyzer and put message with print 'line 1' etc etc.

Thank you for your help.

This is a similar example

```
create procedure procx
as

  declare
    @ind_max  int,
    @ind      int,
    @var_id   int,
    @var_name varchar(3)

  declare @table_x table
  (
    row_id    int identity(1,1),
    id_x      int,
    name_x    varchar(25),
    status_x  int
  )

  insert into @table_x values(1, 'xxx', 0)
  insert into @table_x values(2, 'yyy', 0)
  insert into @table_x values(3, 'zzz', 0)

  set @ind_max = 3
  set @ind = 1

  while (@ind <= @ind_max)
  begin

    print 'line 1'

    select @var_id   = id_x   ,
           @var_name = name_x
    from @table_x
    where row_id = @ind

    -- Forced error id_x is int field
    -- Doesn't show line2, line3 ...
    -- Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure procx, Line 160
    -- Syntax error converting the varchar value 'A' to a column of data type int.
    insert into test ( id_x , name_x )
    values ( 'A' , @var_name )

    if @@error != 0
    begin

      print 'line 2'
      goto next_row

      insert into log_test values(@var_id, 'Error')

    end

    print 'line 3'

    update @table_x
    set status_x = 1
    where row_id = @ind

    print 'line 4'

next_row:
    set @ind = @ind + 1

  end

  print 'line 5'
```

Comment: We need to see your query code.

Comment: If you add the t-sql for the stored procedure as part of your question, it might help get more (and more useful) responses.

Comment: @@error gets reset after every statement. Is it possible there is some statement between the error and the if check?

Comment: You may want to check this out for reference - http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have a statement in between the error-causing statement and the `IF` check. Simplifying the error handling logic here (since it is an extremely vast topic) and ignoring batch-aborting and connection-terminating errors...

This yields the error message and `'Uh oh'`:

```
SELECT 1/0;

PRINT 'Uh oh';

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Error.';
END
```

Since `@@ERROR` gets reset after every statement, it is no longer non-zero, and the `IF` block does not get entered. While the following works as expected, because we are checking `@@ERROR` immediately after the trouble statement:

```
SELECT 1/0;

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Error.';
END
```

If you do have stuff you need to do in between, you can store the value in a variable:

```
DECLARE @err INT;

SELECT 1/0;

SELECT @err = @@ERROR;

PRINT 'Uh oh';

IF @err <> 0
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Error.';
END
```

This will execute both `PRINT` commands.

**EDIT**

Since you now added your code, I can give further insight into why this isn't working in your case. Invalid object is a severity 16 error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure procx, Line 110
>   
> Invalid object name 'test'.

Now, according to [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937483%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), severity 16 does not abort the batch (only 19 and above), but that doesn't mean this is always true. For example, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2011/05/11/errors-raised-with-severity-level-16-may-cause-transactions-into-doomed-state.aspx) which explains that in some cases sev16 *can* abort the batch. I don't have a 2000 instance anywhere around to test this for certain or to investigate workarounds, other than (a) not creating stored procedures that reference objects that don't exist or (b) upgrading to a modern version of SQL Server that has put a little more thought into error handling).

Comment: The test table exists in my database, the error I get is to enter a character value in a number field, I thought that did not abort the procedure because may be there are inconsistency of data from one to another table. This ERP works whith mssql 2000.

Comment: I tryed inserting a null value in a field not null and this way continue with the batch.